# What is implicit expectation $\tilde E$?

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request

What is implicit expectation $\tilde E$? What is the difference between $\tilde E$ and $E$?

Tried to search for a while with no solutions.

It is from random text found online: **http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~veretenn/math3733/le11.pdf**

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm still satisfied with the idea in my Answer that 'implicit' refers to deducing the expectation from a previous assumption or hypothesis--possibly not yet tested or established. Comparison of final displayed expression at the end of your link with the previous lecture mentioned there may give additional insight. Also language used in financial applications may not exactly match that used in theoretical probability/statistics. (Each discipline feels entitled to its own terminology.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just guessing, but it may be an estimate of an expectation based on a particular model. I have seen the notations $\hat E$ and $\tilde E$ used in goodness-of-fit tests.

It may be that the word *implicit* is descriptive of an expectation obtained for a particular method or procedure, and not intended as a formal definition of anything. If you could give example(s) where you have seen the phrase used, you might get a more direct answer.

*Example:* For a chi-squared test of independence in a two-way a contingency table, you might have 100 subjects altogether. Perhaps they have been categorized as to job type and retirement plan preference. Of these, 20 may be clerical employees (a row total) and 30 may favor a retirement plan where pay is deducted for retirement each month (a column total). Then we might say that the estimated probability a randomly
chosen employee is Clerical is $\hat P(C) = \hat P(\mathrm{Clerical}) = 20/100 = 0.2.$
Similarly, we might have $\hat P(M) = \hat P(\mathrm{Monthly Deduction}) = 30/100  =0.3.$

If job type and plan preference were independent, we might conclude
that $\hat P(C \cap M) = .2(.3) = 0.6$ and thus that independence
implies that the expected number in the cell of the table for $C \cap M$
is $\hat E(C\cap M) = n \hat P(C\cap M) = 100(.06) = 6.$ A chi-squared
goodness of fit test would compare $\hat E(C\cap M)$ with the the
*observed* number of Clerical employees who prefer the Monthly plan.

In such a situation where the estimate $\hat E(C\cap M)$ is implied
by the assumption of independence, I can imagine someone calling it
an *implicit expectation*.